# lateinit property has not been initialized - Android Lifecycle issue

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

I get an occasional app crash report which shouldn't occur based on my understanding of the Android lifecycle. Obviously I'm wrong somehow.

I have an Activity which initializes an API interface in the onCreate and provides a method called getApi()

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IApiProvider...{
...
    private lateinit var mApiInterface: ApiInterface
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        mApiInterface = ApiInterface.invoke(
            ConnectivityInterceptor(applicationContext, this),
            AuthorizationInterceptor(this),
            prefs,
            authenticator
        )
        ...
    }

    override fun getApi(): ApiInterface {
        return mApiInterface // THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS
    }

}
```

I also have a Fragment which attempts to grab this Api interface from the activity in the following fashion

```
class MyFragment()...{

    private lateinit var mApiProvider: IApiProvider

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        if (context is IApiProvider) {
            mApiProvider = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("$context must implement IApiProvider")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        if (activity != null) {
            mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
                this,
                MyViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, mApiProvider.getApi()) // This call causes the crash in the Activity
            )
                .get(LapTimingViewModel::class.java)
        }

}
```

So even if the Activity gets recycled due to some Android memory management, shouldn't the Activity onCreate method be executed before the Fragment onCreate method and therefore the mApiInterface should be initialized?

Edit #1: Adding stacktrace

```
2022-03-24 12:45:32.600 23305-23305/hidden.package.name.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: hidden.package.name.debug, PID: 23305
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hidden.package.name.debug/hidden.package.name.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in hidden.package.name.debug:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #47 in hidden.package.name.debug:layout/app_bar_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3527)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3702)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2151)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7844)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in hidden.package.name.debug:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #47 in hidden.package.name.debug:layout/app_bar_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47 in hidden.package.name.debug:layout/app_bar_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property mApiInterface has not been initialized
        at hidden.package.name.MainActivity.getApi(MainActivity.kt:536)
        at hidden.package.name.ui.laptiming.LapTimingFragment.onCreate(LapTimingFragment.kt:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2571)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1707)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1683)
        at hidden.package.name.ui.home.BottomNavigationFragment.onCreate(BottomNavigationFragment.kt:62)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2571)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1707)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1683)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:264)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
2022-03-24 12:45:32.601 23305-23305/hidden.package.name.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at hidden.package.name.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:52)
        at hidden.package.name.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:46)
        at hidden.package.name.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:83)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8114)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8098)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3702)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2151)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7844)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer thanks to @laalto

I changed my Activity onCreate from this:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = mBinding.root
        setContentView(view)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupDrawerNav()

        ...

        mApiInterface = ApiInterface.invoke(
            ConnectivityInterceptor(applicationContext, this),
            AuthorizationInterceptor(this),
            prefs,
            authenticator
        )
     ...
     }
```

to this

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...

        mApiInterface = ApiInterface.invoke(
            ConnectivityInterceptor(applicationContext, this),
            AuthorizationInterceptor(this),
            prefs,
            authenticator
        )
        

        mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = mBinding.root
        setContentView(view)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupDrawerNav()
```

Basically, I only bind the view after the init is done...

Answer (score 1):

Before returning the lateinit property where a crash occurs, you can simply check if that property is initialized or not like this:

```
this::propertyName.isInitialized
```

If the property has not been initialized, you can simply return something else or null which will avoid the crash.

Comment: Good idea but seems like a hack and the Fragment cannot work without the API

Answer (score 0):

After a config change, fragments get restored when you call activity `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. You should have the activity ready for your fragments init at that point. One way to do that is to postpone the `super.onCreate()` call to a later point in your `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - unfortunately pushing the super.onCreate() down didn't help in resolving this.

Comment: Examine the full stacktrace to learn where exactly the restore process is occurring.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I added a stacktrack above - anything you can notice from it?

Comment: Looks like you're adding the fragment via xml layout `fragment` tag. That's quite hard to get right. Consider using either `FragmentContainerView` is xml or add the fragment completely programmatically.

Comment: You gave me an idea which resolved the issue! Thank you so much. I'm unable to upvote because not enough rep :(
I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this 6 lines to codes and your program runes well

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
```